# Getting result of long sentence

Tags: sentence-construction, adverbs

I wrote this sentence

> In our approach, **we rely mainly on the web page's content rather than its structure**, **in order to /so to** provide more maintainable and robust wrappers.

To get result from a long sentence (bold sentence), what are the common constructions (patterns) and words? I used "in order to", could I use "so, to"? I guess the order is also important, and I'd better to place the last sentence in the front. right?!

Comment: Your two possible options are **in order to [do something]** and **so as to [do it]**. You can't just use **so** on its own here.

Comment: The commas after '*approach*' and '*structure*' seem unnecessary, unless you simply state what the approach is, and then explain the reason, then the latter clause (beginning with '*in order to*') can be separated by a comma.

Comment: @VictorBazarov I think I mean to add a clause after said my approach